# Grid or tile algorithm for views within a view

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, algorithm

I am attempting to organize one to six images in a grid with a fairly random layout. I am passing the method an array of images that I want to iterate over and return a view containing the grid of images similar to my example below. What would be the best approach to accomplish this?

**Edit:** I am trying to figure out how to layout each view on the fly. Also, the first grid in count == 5 in the image is incorrect.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say, you have 3 images. You will have 4 possible layouts. Calculate for each layout, in which combination of subviews and images you lose less pixels from the images, when scaling and cropping them to the dimensions of the subimages. If several layouts have the same result, pick one randomly.

Comment: I appreciate the response. Maybe, I wasn't all that clear with what I was asking. At the moment, I'm not to worried about the scaling issues with the images. I am trying to figure out how to layout the subviews on the fly.

Comment: Oh, that is easy: u always hav a two column layout. Devide the number of images by 2. If odd, truncate one and add 1 to the other. In both columns they have the same width, while the height is the column height by its number of images. To get the others layouts, just replace columns by rows.

Comment: To decide if u go with columns or rows, do as I said in my answer.

Comment: Thank you for your help! Should have thought about this question a bit more before asking.

Comment: No, I found it interesting. And if u a burried in a coding project, u easily loose the overview to see the simplest approaches.